# "I'll do it after I finished that" VS "I'll do it after I have finished that"

Tags: grammar

> "I'll do it after I finished that"
>
> "I'll do it after I have finished that"

What's the difference here?

Comment: The difference is that only the second is correct. We use the past tense ('have finished') to refer to events in the future after another event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively the difference is that only one is grammatically correct.

> I'll do it after I have finished that

This is grammatically correct, it correct refers to future tense. I will do this thing once I HAVE completed the other thing.

> I'll do it after I finished that

Grammatically this isn't correct, what could be used instead is

> I'll do it after I finish that

This way there is no need for "have" but both mean similar things, with have suggests you're not working on the focus right now but will be soon in the future, using just finish suggests you're currently actioning this.